# C# Numericupdown Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from a mysql database, and set the value on the numericupdown control. But I get the following error: "Input string was not in a correct format"

This is my code.

```
string quantity;
foreach (DataRow row in WerkData.Rows)
{
    quantity = row["quantity"].ToString();
}
nummericupdown1.value = Convert.ToDecimal(quantity);
```

The value set in the database is 8, when tryint `Testtextbox.text = quantity` it shows me the value 8 in the textbox.

Where does it go wrong?

Comment: How many rows are in `WerkData`? Can you debug the code and check the value of `quantity` right before the call to `Convert.ToDecimal`?

Comment: Fixed it, seems that I forgot to make a seperate datatable for this query.

Comment: be aware of  `DbNull.Value.ToString()` will return an empty string.

Comment: Why is quantity a string in the first place?

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error.